# Ajax call issues

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I'm using `jquery-ui modal dialog` but I create that dynamically like this:

```
$dialog = $('<div id="aa" title="aa">');
$form=$('<form>')

// (...)

$dialog.append($form);
$dialog.appendTo($(document.body));

$dialog.dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 150,
    width: 550,
    modal: true,
    buttons:{
        'Create':function(){
           $.ajax({
               //settings
           });
         }
    }
}
```

All my ajax call's works fine but this one not. All other calls are NOT the dynamically created elements.. Is this the problem?

### SOLVED

Because I'm using `django framework` i forgot to add `csrf_token`

Comment: Where do you append the `$dialog` itself?

Comment: $dialog.appendTo($(document.body));

Comment: this line goes bellow $dialog.append($form);

Comment: On server i get HTTP 403..

Comment: Start by  logging a line to console instead of ajax to see if the button click event is being triggered

Comment: yes is triggered.. data for ajax is calculated by some function and that function i called properly..

Comment: Oh my god! I forgot to add csrf token because i using django!